# Complex numbers - separate real/imaginary parts

Tags: complex-numbers

$$K(\omega) = \frac{1}{1 + j\omega RC}$$

Uhm...How do I separate the real part from the imaginary part here? :U And how can I find the argument? I mean, if the document I got this formula from is right, the argument should be negative...

Comment: What if you multiply the top and bottom of your fraction with $1-j\omega RC$?

Comment: Right, thanks! :P

Comment: You should now be able to answer your own question.

Comment: (Damn, I was hoping people would give OP the chance to answer his own question. Oh well, what can I do...)

Comment: Actually, I did, just forgot about conjugates, this whole complex numbers thing is quite new for me.

Comment: I had in mind you *posting* an answer to your own question, for rep and whatnot, but I suppose it is too late...

Comment: If you just want a numeric values for a particular values of $\omega$ then use a calculator that handles complex numbers, and use the formula as is. (Don't do algebraic huffing and puffing just for the sake of a dumb machine that only works with reals.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ a ratio of complex numbers, multiplying
$$
\frac{z_1}{z_2}\cdot\frac{\overline{z_2}}{\overline{z_2}} = \frac{z_1\overline{z_2}}{z_2\overline{z_2}}
$$
will give you a real denominator ($\overline{z_2}$ is the complex conjugate of $z_2$). Once you do that, you need only write $z_1\overline{z_2} = x + jy$, $x,y\in\Bbb R$, as then
$$
\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{x + jy}{z_2\overline{z_2}} = \frac{x}{z_2\overline{z_2}} + j\frac{y}{z_2\overline{z_2}}.
$$